# Ember.js set embedded subdocument value with input (same form)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am having trouble accessing the values of subdocuments from my form inputs in Ember-data.

Using RESTAdapter, I want to construct a record for 'business information' with an embedded subdocument structure that might look something like this:

```
"businessHours": {
        "monday":{
            "operating-status": "open",
            "from": null,
            "to": null
        }, 
        "tuesday": {
            "operating-status": "open",
            "from": null,
            "to": null
        }
    }
```

Where business hours is just one attribute of the business object. I am attempting to define that subdocument relationship with the following models. **Problem is, the form inputs (code below) are not updating the businessHours attribute in the Ember inspector.** When I save the record, the entire attribute is null.

In the business model (among all the other attributes):

```
businessHours: DS.belongsTo('hours', {async: false}),
```

the 'hours' model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  bizinfo: DS.belongsTo('location.js', {async: false}),
  monday: DS.belongsTo('day', {async: false}),
  tuesday: DS.belongsTo('day', {async: false}),
  wednesday: DS.belongsTo('day', {async: false}),
  thursday: DS.belongsTo('day', {async: false}),
  friday: DS.belongsTo('day', {async: false}),
  saturday: DS.belongsTo('day', {async: false}),
  sunday: DS.belongsTo('day', {async: false})
});
```

And finally the 'day' model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  hours: DS.belongsTo('hours', {async: false}),
  operatingStatus: DS.attr('string'),
  from: DS.attr(),
  to: DS.attr()
});
```

As for templates, I have a business-hours component and feed it the businessHours portion of the model like this:

```
<h3>Business Hours</h3>
{{business-hours hours=model.businessHours}}
```

Then, I set the values on the inputs to equal what I would imagine are those values in the subdocument. Is this where I go wrong?

```
<tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td><select {{value hours.wednesday.operatingStatus}}>
          <option value="closed">Closed</option>
          <option value="open">Open</option>
          <option value="24hr">24hr</option>
    </select></td>
    <td>{{input type="time" value=hours.wednesday.from}}</td>
    <td>{{input type="time" value=hours.wednesday.to}}</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: `bizinfo: DS.belongsTo('location.js', {async: false}),` is a typo, it should be `'location'`.

Comment: ahh thanks @locks -- still, without the typo I am unable to access the data in these subdocuments through my inputs. Is that something I should be able to do? In the ember-inspector, the businessHours attribute of my locations stays null even when I am actively inputting data.